# Postgres PgSQL Alias no reconocido

Tags: postgresql-9.3, plpgsql

hola tengo un tema con este select, y no se estará soportado

es un select que anida 2 tablas en el mismo selec pero este no funciona 
al ejecutar el select funciona todo bien, pero al usarlo en un cursor, no reconoce la columna idresource

[42702] ERROR: column reference "idresource" is ambiguous

alguna sugerencia

```
        open curs_for_items for
          select grupo.ori, grupo.typeitem,grupo.description,sum(grupo.amount) amount, sum(grupo.amounttax) amounttax, max(grupo.idresource) as idresource
        from (
          SELECT
            eve.typeitem,
            eve.description,
            eve.amount,
            eve.amounttax,
            eve.idresource as idresource,
          'EVENT' ori
          FROM event eve
          WHERE idtransaction = numberTransaction
          UNION ALL
          select pr.typeitem, pr.typetax, pr.amount, pr.amounttax, pr.idresource, pr.ori
          from (
          SELECT
            evt.typeitem,
            evt.typetax,
            evt.amount,
            0 AS amounttax,
            (SELECT idresource
             FROM event
             WHERE id = evt.idevent) as idresource,
            'TAX' ori
          FROM eventtax evt
          WHERE idtransaction = numberTransaction
                AND idevent IS NOT NULL
          ) pr
          UNION ALL
          SELECT
            evnull.typeitem,
            evnull.typetax,
            evnull.amount,
            0 AS amounttax,
            (SELECT idresource
             FROM event
             WHERE id IN (SELECT a.idevent
                          FROM eventtax a
                          WHERE a.id = evnull.idtax)) as idresource,
            'TAX' ori
          FROM eventtax evnull
          WHERE idtransaction = numberTransaction
                AND idevent IS NULL
        ) grupo
        group by grupo.ori, grupo.typeitem,grupo.description,grupo.idresource
        order by grupo.idresource;
```

Answer (score 0):

finalmente no logre generar una solucion creo que posstgres a nivel de cursores no soporta este nivel de anidacion de querys, lo resolvi de esta menera cambiando un poco el select

```
        select grupo.ori, grupo.typeitem,grupo.description,sum(grupo.amount) amount, sum(grupo.amounttax) amounttax, max(grupo.idresource) idresource, count(1) cnt
        from (
          SELECT
            eve.typeitem,
            eve.description,
            eve.amount,
            eve.amounttax,
            eve.idresource,
          'EVENT' ori
          FROM event eve
          WHERE idtransaction = numberTransaction
        union all
         SELECT
            evt.typeitem,
            evt.typetax,
            evt.amount,
            0 AS amounttax,
            ev.idresource ,
            'TAX' ori
          FROM eventtax evt, event ev
          WHERE  ev.id = evt.idevent and
            evt.idtransaction = numberTransaction
                AND idevent IS NOT NULL
        UNION ALL
             SELECT
            evt.typeitem,
            evt.typetax,
            evt.amount,
            0 AS amounttax,
            ev.idresource ,
            'TAX' ori
          FROM eventtax evt, event ev, eventtax evt2
          WHERE evt2.id = evt.idtax
            and ev.id = evt2.idevent
            and evt.idtransaction = numberTransaction
            AND evt.idevent IS NULL)
        grupo
        group by grupo.ori, grupo.typeitem,grupo.description,grupo.idresource
        order by grupo.idresource;
```